# Losses for LSTM autoencoder

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm, autoencoder

What choices of losses are there for an LSTM autoencoder? 
Other than Mean Squared Error (MSE), is there a possibility of using anything else? 
If yes, can you please link me to a keras (tf backend) implementation or provide me with one?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset is highly-imbalanced, using "**Median frequency class weighting**" as the loss function other than **MSE reconstruction loss** is recommended.

The following links should help too:

1. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras
2. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3653